# How to install a private bit.dev package in a react project?

Tags: reactjs, bit.dev

I have tried installing a **public** [bit cloud](https://bit.dev/) package in a react project and it works.

```bash
yarn config set '@bit:registry' https://node.bit.dev
yarn add @bit/<scope-name>.<module-name>.<component-name>
```

But how can I intsall a **private** [bit cloud](https://bit.dev/) package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer

**Step 1**

Do `bit login`. This will create a `.npmrc` in your root directory.

- Windows: `"C:\Users\<username>\.npmrc"`
- Mac and Linux: `~/.npmrc`

**Step 2**

Copy the lines starting with `//node.bit` from the file and add that to your local `.npmrc` file in your project directory. Add `always-auth=true` to the end of your `.npmrc`. Eg:

```
@<organization-name>:registry=https://node.bit.cloud
//node.bitsrc.io/:_authToken=xxxxx-bit-token-xxxxx
//node.bit.cloud/:_authToken=xxxxx-bit-token-xxxxx
always-auth=true
```

**Step 3**

Install the packages

```bash
yarn add @<organization-name>/<scope-name>.<module-name>.<component-name>
```